# Yii framework "The page cannot be found!"

Tags: php, yii

I am newbie to yii framework I have comfigured my yii framework to use my own controller to load pages. I have changed my main.php configurations to do this. The controller identifies pages from my sef urls. But when I load the page using my sefurl the page doesn't load and gives "The page cannot be found!" but when I try without sef URL the page loads fine. Please let me what is the issue with this

Comment: Please provide examples of your code, otherwise we will all be guessing in the dark. Please read the documentation on how to create controllers - make sure your functions are named properly, for example "public function actionEdit()", and add the action "Edit" to your access rules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the CUrlManager for using this sef url's  . This may help you i refer it form [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/53/using-search-engine-and-user-friendly-urls/)